# error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'array' is a 'let' constant

Tags: arrays, swift, immutability

```
import Foundation

func contains(array: [Int], rand: Int) -> Bool{
    for number in array {
        if(number == rand){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func quicksort(array: [Int], lowIndex: Int, highIndex: Int){
    if(lowIndex >= highIndex){
        return;
    }

    let pivot: Int = array[highIndex]
    var leftPointer = lowIndex
    var rightPointer = highIndex

    while(leftPointer < rightPointer){
        while(array[leftPointer] <= pivot && leftPointer < rightPointer){
            leftPointer = leftPointer + 1
        }

        while(array[rightPointer] >= pivot && leftPointer < rightPointer){
            rightPointer = rightPointer - 1
        }

            array.swapAt(leftPointer, rightPointer)
    }

    if(array[leftPointer] > array[highIndex]){
        array.swapAt(leftPointer, highIndex)
    } else{
        leftPointer = highIndex
    }

    quicksort(array: array, lowIndex: lowIndex, highIndex: leftPointer - 1)
    quicksort(array: array, lowIndex: leftPointer + 1, highIndex: highIndex)
}

func quicksort(array: [Int]){
    quicksort(array: array, lowIndex: 0, highIndex: array.count - 1)
}

func main(){
    var array = [Int.random(in: 0..<30)]
    var jArray = 0

    while(jArray < 20){
        let rand = Int.random(in: 0..<21)
        if(!contains(array: array, rand: rand)){
            array.append(rand)
            jArray = jArray + 1
        }
        else{}
    }

    print("Before:")
    print(array)
    print("\nAfter:")
    quicksort(array: array)
    print(array)    
}



main()
```

I tried to implement the Quicksort like that in swift and the swapAt method throws an error which says: **error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'array' is a 'let' constant.**
I tried several fixes but somehow nothing seemed to work so I hope that someone here can help me with that, thank you.

Comment: You want `inout`, because `array` inside `quicksort(array: [Int], lowIndex: Int, highIndex: Int)` is a `let`. But you want to modify it and keep that modification outside of the method. And use `&value` when calling the method: `quicksort(array: inout [Int])` & `quicksort(array: &array, lowIndex: 0, highIndex: array.count - 1)` (but that's to apply to a few places, not only this one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters to a function are effectively `let` constants. There are two ways you can resolve the problem which represent different programming paradigms. The first is to make the parameters `inout` and the second is to return the sorted array.

Using `inout`

```
func quicksort(array: inout [Int], lowIndex: Int, highIndex: Int)
{
    // sort the array
}
```

Returning the sorted array

```
func quicksort(array: [Int]) -> [Int]
{
    var sortingArray = array
    // Do the pivot stuff

    return quicksort(lower bit of sortingArray) + quicksort(upper bit of sortingArray)
}
```

You can do some jazzy stuff with generics and array slices in the latter case to make it look nice and eliminate the need to pass indexes.